# How to make the dialogue widget stay on top of all windows after its multiple child windows called by the "exec_" method are closed?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a GUI of PyQt5. It provides a push button for users to open a QFileDialog widget. If users select a file in the QFileDialog widget, a message box should pop out to ask users to confirm his/her selection. Everything works as expected by far. Then, after users click either the 'Yes' or 'No' button on the message box, the message box will close. And if it is the 'Yes' button which is clicked, a function "do_task" will be called. But ,to my surprise, the main dialogue which ought to stay on top of all windows afterwards falls back and ends up being on the second top position.

Can any one explain to me why it occurs in this way? I thought that it is relevant to the usage of the "exec_" method for the "QFileDialog" and "QMessageBox" widget. But I need to use the "exec_" method to call the "QMessageBox" widget so that the users's selection can be passed to the main program. How should I change my code to make the main dialogue stay on top of all windows after the "Yes" button on the message box is clicked?  ( I try not to use the "setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)" method because I don't want the main dialogue always stay on top even when it is not selected by users. )

Below is the code for my main program:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

from my_dialog import Ui_MyDialog

class MyMainDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_MyDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
   
        super(MyMainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._select_config_file)

    def _select_config_file(self):

        fileDlg = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)
        fileDlg.fileSelected.connect(self.call_msg_box)
        fileDlg.exec_()

    def call_msg_box(self):

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily('Calibri')
        font.setPointSize(12)

        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
        msgBox.setFont(font)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle('Information')
        msgBox.setText('Are you going to use the '
                       '\nselected file as the config?')
        msgBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Question)
        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        reply = msgBox.exec_()
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes: self.do_task()

    def do_task(self):

        for i in range(3): print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainDialog()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Below is my code for GUI in the module "my_dialog.py":

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MyDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, MyDialog):
        MyDialog.setObjectName("MyDialog")
        MyDialog.resize(177, 50)
        MyDialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        MyDialog.setFont(font)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/ORing_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MyDialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(MyDialog)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(75, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MyDialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(MyDialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyDialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, MyDialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MyDialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("MyDialog", "Config File Selection Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MyDialog", "Select"))
```

I hope that my problem about the change of the position of the main dialogue (which is the MyMainDialogue instance) can be illustrated more clearly with the following screenshots. They are the screenshots of my desktop.

Screenshot 1:
First, I ran the program from a Command Prompt of Windows 7 which was in the upside of the screenshot. I also launched the Chrome browser which was in the left side of the screenshot. And the main dialogue of my program was almost in the center of the screenshot and it was on top of the Command Prompt and the Chrome browser.

[image: Screenshot 1. The main dialogue was on top of all windows.]

Screenshot 2:
Then, I clicked the 'select' button of the main dialogue and selected a file in the file dialogue which closed afterwards. A message box popped out. At this time, the message box was in the top of all windows. And the main dialogue was in the second top position but it was still on top of the Command Prompt and the Chrome browser.

[image: Screenshot 2: The message box showed up and the main dialogue was still on top of the Command Prompt and the Chrome browser.]

Screenshot 3:
I clicked the 'yes' button of the message box and it closed. But the main dialogue was not in the top of the Command Prompt anymore although it was still on top of the Chrome browser. What I expected was that the main dialogue should stay on top of the Command Prompt and the Chrome browser.

[image: Screenshot 3: The Command Prompt was on top of my main dialogue.]

Comment: "the main dialogue which ought to stay on top of all windows afterwards falls back and ends up being on the second top position." With "main dialog", do you mean the `MyMainDialog` instance? And "second top position" related to what?

Comment: @musicamante: Thank you for pointing this out. I didn't make my statement clear enough. Yes, by "the main dialogue", I refer to the "MyMainDialogue" instance. And by "the second top position", I mean that the main dialogue of my program is not on top of the other windows anymore as you can see in the last screenshot which I just added to my question above.